# Python + GStreamer: How to make music audio loop exactly on beat?

Tags: python, gstreamer

I am trying to create an audio clip looper in Python and GTK4, and I've run into an issue with GStreamer and synchronisation. When I loop a clip, there is quite some noticeable latency before it starts playing again.

I've come across [this page](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/clocks.html?gi-language=python) talking about clocks, and I understand I somehow need to compensate for the output latency, but without code examples, it's hard for me to make any sense of it.

I'm new to GStreamer, so I'm aware that my method might be totally bonkers, but this example illustrates where I am now (project with loop files available [here](https://gitlab.com/mrzapp/python-looper-test)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import gi
import os
import threading

gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
gi.require_version('GObject', '2.0')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GLib

class Looper:
    beats_per_minute = 90
    beats_per_cycle = 4
    beats_until_cycle = 0

    pipeline_1 = None
    pipeline_2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        Gst.init(sys.argv[1:])
    
        self.pipeline_1 = Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=file://' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/loop_1.wav')
        self.pipeline_2 = Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=file://' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/loop_2.wav')
    
        self.on_beat()

    def on_beat(self):
        if self.beats_until_cycle < 1:
            self.beats_until_cycle = self.beats_per_cycle

            # Loop audio here
            self.pipeline_1.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            self.pipeline_1.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            
            self.pipeline_2.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            self.pipeline_2.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            
        self.beats_until_cycle -= 1

        threading.Timer(60.0 / self.beats_per_minute, self.on_beat).start()

Looper()
```

I tried restarting the pipelines in a threaded infinite loop, but it causes latency this way.

Answer (score 0):

To loop an audio clip exactly on beat, you need to synchronize the playback with a clock that represents the beat tempo. In GStreamer, you can use the Gst.Clock and the Gst.ClockTime objects to achieve this.

```
import sys
import gi
import os

gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
gi.require_version('GObject', '2.0')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GLib

class Looper:
    beats_per_minute = 90
    beats_per_cycle = 4
    beats_until_cycle = 0
    clock = None

    pipeline_1 = None
    pipeline_2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        Gst.init(sys.argv[1:])
        self.clock = Gst.SystemClock.obtain()

        self.pipeline_1 = Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=file://' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/loop_1.wav')
    self.pipeline_1.use_clock(self.clock)
    
        self.pipeline_2 = Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=file://' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/loop_2.wav')
        self.pipeline_2.use_clock(self.clock)
    
        self.on_beat()

     def on_beat(self):
        if self.beats_until_cycle < 1:
            self.beats_until_cycle = self.beats_per_cycle


        self.pipeline_1.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.pipeline_1.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.pipeline_1.seek_simple(Gst.Format.TIME, Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH | Gst.SeekFlags.KEY_UNIT, 0)
        
        self.pipeline_2.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.pipeline_2.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.pipeline_2.seek_simple(Gst.Format.TIME, Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH | Gst.SeekFlags.KEY_UNIT, 0)

    self.beats_until_cycle -= 1


    beat_duration = Gst.ClockTime.new(60 * Gst.SECOND // self.beats_per_minute)
    time_now = self.clock.get_time()
    next_beat_time = ((time_now // beat_duration) + 1) * beat_duration
    time_until_next_beat = next_beat_time - time_now

    GLib.timeout_add(time_until_next_beat // Gst.MSECOND, self.on_beat)
```

Looper()

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks legit, but it seems Gst.ClockTime doesn't exist, at least not in the Python binding. I get this error when running your code:

    AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gst' object has no attribute 'ClockTime'. Did you mean: 'ClockType'?

I see ClockTime referenced [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstclock.html?gi-language=c#GstClockTime), but only for the C language